# Failed to find Flask application or factory in module 'app'. Use 'FLASK_APP=app:name' to specify one

Tags: python, flask

```
>>> flask run
 * Serving Flask app 'app' (lazy loading)
 * Environment: development
 * Debug mode: on
Usage: flask run [OPTIONS]
Try 'flask run --help' for help.

Error: Failed to find Flask application or factory in module 'app'. Use 'FLASK_APP=app:name' to specify one.
```

Getting this error when trying to make a package from my simple `flask` app

Also it can be another error:

```
Error: While importing 'app', an ImportError was raised.
```

And maybe it is

```
>>> flask run
 * Serving Flask app 'app' (lazy loading)
 * Environment: development
 * Debug mode: on
Usage: flask run [OPTIONS]
Try 'flask run --help' for help.

Error: Could not import 'app.app'.
```

But I'm doing everything by the docs "Large Applications as Packages":
https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/patterns/packages/

Answer (score 0):

In my case renaming app name from `app` to another one helped.

Maybe it was some kind of namespace error, because my package was `./app` and `Flask app object` variable in `__init__.py` was named `app` *(Despite Miguel in [his tutorial did it](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world) the same way)*

In general, while developing web applications you have to be careful with names like `wsgi` - they can be reserved.

I am executing  `set FLASK_APP=module`, `set FLASK_ENV=development`, `pip install -e .` and `flask run` commands in the first (upper) `module` directory.

**And maybe you only need to revert changes from [flask doc tutorial](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/patterns/packages/) returning to the file structure without `__init__.py` and with normal `app.py`. After that delete all `__pycache__` folders and repeat this tutorial again**